# How to optimize the below jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

```
    $('#addmore').click(function() {
        var row = $('.crossref:last').clone();
        $('.crossref:last').after(row);
    });
```

Above code is used to clone some HTML & paste the cloned HTML right after the last cloned row. I have a lot of addmore buttons with the same functionality. I'm really concerned with this code snippet.

I'm wondering is there a way to optimize this code?

Comment: "I'm really concerned with this code snippet." May I ask why? Do you have a specific performance issue with _that_ specific piece of code?

Comment: `I have a lot of addmore buttons with the same functionality` you should be using a `class` for them then, not an `id` - assuming they are all in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the `clone()` and `after()` in to one line, which would also remove one of the duplicate `.crossref:last` selectors:

```
$('#addmore').click(function() {
    $('.crossref:last').after(function() { $(this).clone(); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better

```
$('#addmore').click(function() {
    var lastEl = $('.crossref:last');
    lastEl.after(lastEl.clone());
});
```